# How can i determine all routes from one node to another by using adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, adjacency-matrix

```
mat = [[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]
```

[network image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdx8J.png)

How can i determine route from adjacency matrix?

Thanks in advance for your interest..

Expected result: *from 1 to 4:*

1-2-4

1-3-4

Comment: You'd use something like DFS or look into using a library like `networkx`

Comment: What did you try so far? And what were your results?

Comment: Actually i tried to do some iterative list operations but i got nothing for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) for this.

Example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import numpy as np
>>> g = nx.from_numpy_array(np.array(mat)) 
>>> g = nx.relabel_nodes(g, {i:i+1 for i in range(len(mat))})
>>> list(nx.all_simple_paths(g, 1, 4))
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]]
```